# Combining CountVectorizer and ngrams in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, countvectorizer

Have a task to classify male and female names, using ngrams.
So, have a dataframe like:

```
    name    is_male
Dorian      1
Jerzy       1
Deane       1
Doti        0
Betteann    0
Donella     0
```

The specific requarement is to use

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
```

for this task, to create ngrams (n=2,3,4)

I made a list of names, then used ngrams:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()

test_ngrams = []
for name in name_list:
    test_ngrams.append(list(ngrams(name,3)))
```

Now I need to somehow vectorize all this to use for classification, I try

```
X_train = count_vect.fit_transform(test_ngrams)
```

Recieve:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I understand that a list is wrong type of input here, can someone please explain how I should do it, so I later can use MultinomialNB, for example. Am I doing it the right way at all?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about names which are both male and female? Probably it's better to have 2 features instead of 1 (is_male, is_female).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are passing a sequence of lists to the vectorizer which is why you are receiving the `AttributeError`. Instead, you should pass an iterable of strings. From the `CountVectorizer` [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer):

> **fit_transform(raw_documents, y=None)**
>
> Learn the vocabulary dictionary and return term-document matrix.
>
> This is equivalent to fit followed by transform, but more efficiently implemented.
>
> **Parameters:** **raw_documents** : iterable
>
> An *iterable which yields either str*, unicode or file objects.

To answer your question, the `CountVectorizer` is capable of creating N-grams by using `ngram_range` (the following produces bigrams):

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))

corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This is the second second document.',
]
X = count_vect.fit_transform(corpus)

print(count_vect.get_feature_names())
['first document', 'is the', 'second document', 'second second', 'the first', 'the second', 'this is']
```

---

**Update:**

Since you mentioned that you *have to* generate ngrams using NLTK, we need to override parts of the default behaviour of the `CountVectorizer`. Namely, the `analyzer` which converts raw strings into features:

> **analyzer** : string, {‘word’, ‘char’, ‘char_wb’} or callable
>
> [...]
>
> If a callable is passed it is used to extract the sequence of features
>   out of the raw, unprocessed input.

Since we already provide ngrams, an identity function suffices:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(
    analyzer=lambda x:x
)
```

**Complete Example combining NLTK ngrams and CountVectorizer:**

```
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This is the second second document.',
]

def build_ngrams(text, n=2):
    tokens = text.lower().split()
    return list(nltk.ngrams(tokens, n))

corpus = [build_ngrams(document) for document in corpus]

count_vect = CountVectorizer(
    analyzer=lambda x:x
)

X = count_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
print(count_vect.get_feature_names())
[('first', 'document.'), ('is', 'the'), ('second', 'document.'), ('second', 'second'), ('the', 'first'), ('the', 'second'), ('this', 'is')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to use CountVectorizer alone for this task. To use ngrams from nltk is just a part of task, so I'm not sure how to combine them together.

Comment: @AlexNikitin ok, can you please update the question with your specific requirement?

Comment: Updated. The only specific requirement is to use 'from nltk.util import ngrams' for this task. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexNikitin I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works!